# How can I configure PipeWire for PulseAudio comparability?

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, pipewire

Currently, I do not think my PulseAudio shim for PipeWire is working. When I run `pactl info`, I'm getting a *"Connection refused"* error,

```
$ pactl info
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

When I try to run pavumixer, I get

> Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait...

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The question to be honest makes zero sense. PipeWire re-implements PulseAudio API, it's not just "compatible", it's a perfect replacement for PA. Also, are you sure you meant "comparability" not "compatibility"? "my PulseAudio shim for PipeWire is working" - this is also quite nonsensical.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewriting your question to make it more grounded in reality.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov explain what pipewire does then without `pipewire-pulse.service` running or without wireplumber?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the PW architecture but yet it needs three services in order to work, `pipewire.service` (PipeWire Multimedia Service), `pipewire-pulse.service` (PipeWire PulseAudio) and `wireplumber.service` (Multimedia Service Session Manager).

Comment: So what's the objection to calling pipewire-pulse.server a "shim". My understanding: It can be turned off. It's not required. It services for PulseAudio compat?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov BTW, I want you to correct on this if I'm wrong. I just not an expert either. When a replacement comes with an optional service that provides compat, I call that a shim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make sure you have `wireplumber`

First make sure you [follow the directions on the Debian testing wiki for setting up PulseAudio.](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire#Debian_Testing.2FUnstable) Note you do not want to `pipewire-media-session`. Make sure that's totally gone (taking one command from the wiki),

```bash
apt install wireplumber pipewire-media-session-
```

## Confirm service is running

Make sure the `pipewire-pulse` service is started,

```bash
systemctl --user status pipewire-pulse.socket pipewire-pulse.service
```

That should return something like this,

```
● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-02 12:35:10 CDT; 2min 21s ago
```

To be properly configured either,

1. The service should be active, or
2. The socket should be active.
3. Or both, ;)

If it's not, you can start just the socket, **preferred** -- if nothing uses it nothing happens (the daemon is lazy-loaded)

```bash
systemctl start --user pipewire-pulse.socket
```

Or, just start both (**NOT** preferred, no real gain just not lazy)

```bash
systemctl start --user pipewire-pulse.socket pipewire-pulse.service
```