# How do I change the playback destination of a running stream in pipewire?

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, pipewire

Previously when I was using PulseAudio and I would open `pavucontrol` I could see where all my streams where going in the Playback tab.

Now that I've upgrading to PipeWire, I do not see anything playing in the Playback tab. Subsequently if I'm watching a YouTube video and plug in a USB audio device, it doesn't move the stream. Is there a UI to change the stream destination in PipeWire?

This is all I see when I'm playing a stream on YouTube, just one thing that says "System Sounds" and no place to change the card.

[image: Current playback tab in pavucontrol with stream playing on YouTube]

Answer (score 1):

If Chrome (or anything) starts before the `pipewire-pulse.service` this is what happens. Make sure your pipiewire-pulse service is running, or at least the socket is open which will start the service when something tries to connect,

Here is a [good tutorial to check that it's working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708387/3285)

Only then can you kill and Restart chrome and see the Chrome streams,

```
killall chromium-browser
```

Substitute your browser name for `chromium-browser` if your distro calls it something else.